# How to pass a php array to a postgres query with any condition

Tags: php, postgresql

i wrote the following code:

```
<?php
    $listO = $_POST["letter"];

    //print_r($listO);
    //Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C)

    function to_pg_array($set) {
    settype($set, 'array'); // can be called with a scalar or array
    $result = array();
    foreach ($set as $t) {
        if (is_array($t)) {
            $result[] = to_pg_array($t);
        } else {
            $t = str_replace('"', '\\"', $t); // escape double quote
            if (! is_numeric($t)) // quote only non-numeric values
                $t = '"' . $t . '"';
            $result[] = $t;
        }
    }
    return '{' . implode(",", $result) . '}'; // format

    }

    $pg_array_listO = to_pg_array($listO);

    //print_r($pg_array_list_organisms);
    //{"A","B","C"}

    $conn = pg_connect("host=X dbname=Y user=Z");

    $result = pg_query_params($conn, 'SELECT count(cp.id)
    FROM cp, act, a, t
    WHERE t.tid = a.tid AND
    a.aid = act.aid AND
    act.m = cp.m AND
    t.n = $1 AND
    act.st = $2 AND
    t.o LIKE ANY(ARRAY[$3])', array($t1, $a2, $pg_array_listO));

    while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {echo $row[0];}

?>
```

However i can't figure out how to pass the array `$pg_array_listO` to the postgres query. The function `to_pg_array` converts the php array into postgres array but still don't work. How can i do this?

Comment: whats `var_dump($listO)`?..

Comment: ´array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(1) "B" [2]=> string(1) "C" } ´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postgres array looks like `'{list}'` :

```
t=# select array['a','b','c'];
  array
---------
 {a,b,c}
(1 row)
```

so you need to get rid of double quotes, otherwise postgres understands literals as identities.

Eg with `$pg_array_listO = str_replace('"', '\\"',to_pg_array($listO))` or smth smarter - sorry - I'm not good in php

additionally modify `ANY(ARRAY[$3])` to `ANY('$3'::text[])`, cos `array[]` or `'{}'::text[]` would be accepted

**update**
based on

> ```
>  //print_r($pg_array_list_organisms);
>     //{"A","B","C"}
> ```

I expect this to work:

```
$result = pg_query_params($conn, "SELECT count(cp.id)
FROM cp, act, a, t
WHERE t.tid = a.tid AND
a.aid = act.aid AND
act.m = cp.m AND
t.n = $1 AND
act.st = $2 AND
t.o LIKE ANY($3)", array($t1, $a2, str_replace('"', '',to_pg_array($listO))));
```

**mind I changed quotes and SQL and `str_replace` for $3 variable**

a working example of this approach:

```
t=# select 'a' like any('{a,b,c}'::text[]);
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Sorry i'm starrting with php. It doesn't me any error, simply don't echo result. How can i debugg?

Comment: No, simple doesn't echo the result :/

Comment: I found how to do it! Just needed to replace ANY('$3') for ANY($3), Thank you!

Comment: ha! quite reasonable for parametrized query :) updated the answer. thanks